# Passing shell commands with Python os.system() or subprocess.check_call()

Tags: python

I'm trying to call 'sed' from Python and having troubles passing the command line via either subprocess.check_call() or os.system().

I'm on Windows 7, but using the 'sed' from Cygwin (it's in the path).

If I do this from the Cygwin shell, it works fine:

```
$ sed 's/&amp;nbsp;/\&nbsp;/g' <"C:foobar" >"C:foobar.temp"
```

In Python, I've got the full pathname I'm working with in "name".  I tried:

```
command = r"sed 's/&amp;nbsp;/\&nbsp;/g' " +  "<" '\"' + name + '\" >' '\"' + name + '.temp' + '\"'
subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)
```

All the concatenation is there to make sure I have double quotes around the input and output filenames (in case there are blank spaces in the Windows file path).

I also tried it replacing the last line with:

```
os.system(command)
```

Either way, I get this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command
'amp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'nbsp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Yet, as I said, it works OK from the console.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can I suggest that you skip sed completely, and just write this as a four-line Python script?

Comment: You can't use shell constructs like `<` or `>` in the iterable, since `check_call` just quotes them. You'd have to combine them into a string.... but listen to Ned... he knows his stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Ned Batchelder's [assessment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11623031/355230), but think what you might want to consider using the following code because it likely does what you ultimately want to accomplish which can be done easily with the help of Python's `fileinput` module:

```
import fileinput

f = fileinput.input('C:foobar', inplace=1)
for line in f:
    line = line.replace('&amp;nbsp;', '&nbsp;')
    print line,
f.close()
print 'done'
```

This will effectively update the given file in place as use of the keyword suggests. There's also an optional `backup=` keyword -- not used above -- which will save a copy of the original file if desired.

BTW, a word of caution about using something like `C:foobar` to specify the file name because on Windows it means a file of that name in whatever the current directory is on drive C:, which might not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks; that was just an example.  The file paths come from os.walk; I'm trying to process a whole tree full of files (hundreds of files).

Comment: @nerdfever.com: Well, if you're using `os.walk` to gather the file names to process, it makes even more sense to process each one within Python as well -- something which is likely going to be quicker as well as easier than using an external program to do it.

Answer (score 5):

The shell used by subprocess is probably not the shell you want.  You can specify the shell with `executable='path/to/executable'`.  Different shells have different quoting rules.

Even better might be to skip `subprocess` altogether, and write this as pure Python:

```
with open("c:foobar") as f_in:
    with open("c:foobar.temp", "w") as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            f_out.write(line.replace('&amp;nbsp;', '&nbsp;'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that, in Windows Python, it's not actually *using* the CygWin shell to run your command, it's instead using `cmd.exe`.

And, `cmd` doesn't play well with single quotes the way `bash` does.

You only have to do the following to confirm that:

```
c:\pax> echo hello >hello.txt

c:\pax> type "hello.txt"
hello

c:\pax> type 'hello.txt'
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I think the best idea would be to use Python itself to process the file. The Python language is a cross-platform one which is meant to remove all those platform-specific inconsistencies, such as the one you've just found.